# Fscanf with Dynamic Arrays

Tags: c, scanf, dynamic-arrays

I have a problem. Whenever I try to read from a file to a dynamic array the values are just random.

```
int* aaNo;
int* bbKod;
int* ccPuan;
int* ddOffset;
 aaNo=(int*)malloc(buffer * sizeof(int));
 bbKod=(int*)malloc(buffer * sizeof(int));
 ccPuan=(int*)malloc(buffer * sizeof(int));
 ddOffset=(int*)malloc(buffer * sizeof(int));
//int aaNo[buffer],bbKod[buffer],ccPuan[buffer],ddOffset[buffer];
int line[100],o=0;
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),veri))
{
    fscanf(veri,"%d %d %d %d",&aaNo[o],&bbKod[o],&ccPuan[o],&ddOffset[o]);
    o++;
}
```

And this is the file I want to read:

```
9 2 34 4225420
7 4 24 42205436
0 3 62 4225452
0 1 45 4225468
9 1 61 4225484
4 1 42 4225500
8 1 91 4225516
8 2 53 4225532
6 2 21 4225548
4 5 95 4225564
5 5 71 4225580
5 2 12 4225596
1 4 35 4225612
7 3 11 4225628
1 3 73 4225644
1 1 11 4225660
5 3 47 4225676
2 5 57 4225692
7 2 23 4225708
6 4 78 4225724
1 5 90 4225740
4 3 6 4225756
6 3 64 4225772
3 1 5 4225788
2 4 70 4225804
2 1 1 4225820
9 3 29 4225836
6 5 54 4225852
8 3 66 4225868
5 1 8 4225884
7 1 26 4225900
6 1 38 4225916
0 2 29 4225932
8 5 15 4225948
9 5 4 4225964
2 2 6 4225980
7 5 21 4225996
9 4 72 4226012
5 4 77 4226028
4 2 12 4226044
3 2 61 4226060
0 4 67 4226076
2 3 31 4226092
3 5 50 4226108
3 4 66 4226124
4 4 91 4226140
1 2 57 4226156
0 5 83 4226172
3 3 9 4226188
8 4 88 4226204
```

if I can get some help it'd be great thanks.

Comment: Either `fgets` or `fscanf`? Choose one

Comment: Yup I fixed it thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only scanning every other line. `fgets()` in the `while` condition reads one line, then `fscanf()` reads the next line and extracts the variables from it.

You can use `fgets()` to read the line, then use `sscanf()` to extract the variables form that line.

```
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),veri))
{
    sscanf(line,"%d %d %d %d",&aaNo[o],&bbKod[o],&ccPuan[o],&ddOffset[o]);
    o++;
}
```

Or you can do the scanning in the `while` condition.

```
while(fscanf(veri,"%d %d %d %d",&aaNo[o],&bbKod[o],&ccPuan[o],&ddOffset[o]) == 4)
{
    o++;
}
```

The `line` variable is not needed in the second version.

Full program that has been tested to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *veri;
    veri = fopen("input.txt","r");
    
    int* aaNo;
    int* bbKod;
    int* ccPuan;
    int* ddOffset;

    int buffer=0; 
    int c; 
    for (c = getc(veri); c != EOF; c = getc(veri)) { 
        if (c == '\n') 
            buffer = buffer + 1; 
    }
    fseek(veri, 0, SEEK_SET); // Go back to beginning to re-read file

    aaNo=(int*)malloc(buffer * sizeof(int));
    bbKod=(int*)malloc(buffer * sizeof(int));
    ccPuan=(int*)malloc(buffer * sizeof(int));
    ddOffset=(int*)malloc(buffer * sizeof(int));

    int o=0;
    while(fscanf(veri,"%d %d %d %d",&aaNo[o],&bbKod[o],&ccPuan[o],&ddOffset[o]) == 4)
    {
        o++;
    }
    fclose(veri);

    // Print aray contents
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", aaNo[i], bbKod[i], ccPuan[i], ddOffset[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I implemented the second one to my code. But I still get random numbers whenever I run it. (Here is what my buffer looks like because someone on another forum asked for it: 
 int buffer=0;
    char c;
    for (c = getc(veri); c != EOF; c = getc(veri))
        {

        if (c == '\n') 
            buffer = buffer + 1;
        }

Comment: Try adding 1 to `buffer` at the end, in case the file doesn't end with newline.

Comment: Did it but still random numbers for example I am reading 
9 2 34 4225420
7 4 24 42205436
0 3 62 4225452

and it prints out: 
12452176 12452176
12482624 12482624
544039282 1342187830

Comment: It works for me. Maybe the problem is in the code that prints the arrays.

Comment: I tried setting every element of the array to zero then reading from file appearently the fscanf isnt working properly because it still is zero after reading it.

Comment: I've added my full program that works.

Comment: I'm dumb I forgot to fseek the file to the start again once i read it for the buffer. Thanks a lot again man.